# Import IntelliJ key mapping in to Rider IDE

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Is it possible to import IntelliJ (Version: 2018.1.3) key mappings (or all settings) in to other JetBrains IDE's specifically Rider (Version: 2018.1)?

From what I can tell this is only possible when moving settings across new installation of the same IDE.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this:

Go to -> File -> Export Settings -> choose everything and click ok to save it somewhere

This will export a .jar, that contains everything, like code highlighting, shortcuts and plugins, it is really the whole IDEA settings. Then do the same thing with import and choose the exported .jar file. Now everything should look and feel the same.

Some things to notice:
 - The colouring might be different in some edge cases, as a comment from html and c# looks different. So exporting phpstorm settings to rider might look funny sometimes.
 - Shortcuts also are sometimes not 100% correct, as there are some different workflows in the ideas. Like Rider uses ctrl + . for auto completion where the other ideas do it somehow different. But those are very few occasions (2-3 at max) and not very annoying.

You should just be aware of it. But other than this, exporting settings and plugins could not be easier!

Answer (score 1):

Marquis Blount, yes you can do it if your keymap based on IDEA keymap with name available in Rider.